# Assign into variable value from imported file

Tags: python, variables, import

I'm trying to assign into variable SQL statement from another file which I imported. 
Other filename: Table1.py contain variable `SQL="Select * from column1"`
My current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

datefrom = raw_input("Please enter date from YYYY-MM-DD: ")
dateto = raw_input("Please enter date to YYYY-MM-DD: ")
tablename = raw_input("Please enter tablename: ")
__import__(tablename)
var= '%s.SQL' % tablename
print var
```

All what I got is:
"Table1.SQL"

So, I imported first table name which I got as input, then trying to put into variable "var" value of "SQL" variable from Table1.py file. Of course I want it to stay quite dynamic as know because there will be more than one sql file.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are loading modules at runtime you need to store the module object into a variable and then access its variables normally.

```
table_module = __import__(tablename)
table_sql = table_module.SQL
print table_sql
```

Now, if you want to modify the statement, you can just use simple string manipulation in table_sql variable.